# Authorize.net TLS Disablement Notice civicrm

Tags: authorize.net

what are the changes I need to make to make sure authorize.net works perfectly after authorize.net has sent this message as given below

> Your Payment Gateway ID: 
>   Dear Authorize.Net Merchant:
>   As you may be aware, new PCI DSS requirements state that all payment systems must disable early TLS by 2018.
>   TLS FAQs
>   Merchant Interface
>   Transport Layer Security (TLS), is a technology used to encrypt sensitive information sent via the Internet. TLS is the replacement for Secure Sockets Layer (SSL).
>   In preparation for this requirement, Authorize.Net plans to disable TLS 1.0 and TLS 1.1 on the following dates:
>
> Sandbox: COMPLETE Production: September 18, 2017
>
> We have disabled the sandbox in advance of production to allow you and
>   your developer time to test your website or payment solution and
>   ensure you are no longer using TLS 1.0 or 1.1 prior to September 18th.
>
> Please contact your web developer or payment solution provider, as
>   well as your web hosting company, to confirm that they can support TLS
>   1.2 for your API connections.

Answer (score 3):

See [this blog post](https://civicrm.org/blog/yashodha/are-you-ready-for-tls-12-update-cant-escape-it) which has specific instructions.

Comment: It's good that we have this blog post ... but I can see someone being very confused by the way it is presented. Anything wrong with just starting by `curl https://www.howsmyssl.com` and looking at the TLS version used to connect?

Comment: @EliLisseck thanks for your comment which seemed to be very easy to test server compatibility with TLSv1.2 I used the curl https://www.howsmyssl.com and I get output as html page and I can see  this particular html i.e. "<p><span class="label okay">Good</span> Your client is using
          TLS 1.2, the most modern version of the encryption
          protocol. It gives you access to the fastest, most secure
          encryption possible on the web.</p>
"  which says that my server is using TLS 1.2 so does that confirm that my environment is ready for the Authorize.net TLS1.1 disablement ?

Comment: @harshal I asked it as a question because i'm not 100% sure if the curl command line tool uses the same library as the PHP CURL (provided by cURL project very confusing to me XD)... but if it were... it would be easier .. and I think it does. My server is using NSS and I double checked that the version number was post-TLS 1.2 support as per the blog post to be certain.