# what type of protocol and api connection is used for authorize.net

Tags: authorize.net

Authorize.net will disable older protocols, TLS 1.0 and TLS 1.1, which are highly vulnerable to security breaches. They will be disabled by Authorize.Net on February 28, 2018

What type of protocol and API connection does CiviCRM use?

Comment: This question might be deemed a duplicate of https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/19503/authorize-net-tls-disablement-notice-civicrm?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CiviCRM will communicate with AuthorizeNet using whatever versions of TLS are enabled on your server.

To see if your server is using TLS 1.2, go to https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest and put in your url

in the Configuration section of the report it will list the TLS versions supported.  [image]

Comment: I also just found this little one liner that will tell you what versions are available on your server
`openssl ciphers -v | awk '{print $2}' | sort | uniq`
but it seems to print all those available and not only those enabled. 
the machine in the image above that has only 1.2 enabled gave this result 
`$ openssl ciphers -v | awk '{print $2}' | sort | uniq`
`SSLv3
TLSv1
TLSv1.2`

Comment: When CiviCRM is making a request to Authorize.net (transaction setup & submission), it's PHP that requires support for TLS v1.2. When Authorize.net is making a request to CiviCRM (eg IPN), it's your webserver (or SSL terminator) that requires TLS v1.2. The SSLLabs test covers only the second of those scenarios; the former can be found in the output of `phpinfo()` or `php -i | grep -i tls`. **For most servers these will be the same** (in which case the `openssl` test is fine), but you really want to be checking the CiviCRM-to-Authorize.net route IMO. Or just run a test transaction 

Comment: a big +1 for the extra info and details. Thanks Chris